# RichTextBox does not constantly update when used as text status display

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I'm trying to use a RichTextBox as a status display but it is not updating every time I append to the text of the RichTextBox. A regular multiline TextBox will update everytime new text is appended to it, but I would prefer to use the RichTextBox. Is there some sort of property that needs to be set to see the updates?

**UPDATE:**
Also, how would I automatically make it scroll down every a message is displayed?

Like I said, if I replace the RichTextBox with a TextBox, I can see each line of the messages as they are getting written out and it will also automatically scroll down to the bottom to display the latest text added.

```
void UpdateStatus(string textMessage)
{
  if (InvokeRequired)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateStatus(textMessage)));
    return;
  }

  richTextBox.AppendText(textMessage + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Post your code what have you tried and is not working ??

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3):

An easy and quick fix would be

`Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: Where would I do this at in my form?

Comment: put that statement after everytime you append a new text.

Comment: this is hack - you should not consider this a solution to the problem if you block the UI thread.

Comment: @BrokenGlass : You are right, this is a quick and dirty fix. should I delete the answer as it may be misleading?

Answer (score 1):

To make RichTextBox scroll automatically, please use *ScrollToCaret* method:

```
richTextBox.AppendText("Hello");    
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Yes, TextBox does auto-scroll to caret by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *looks* like it should be working, make sure you check the right `InvokeRequired` flag:

```
void UpdateStatus(string textMessage)
{
  if (richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
  {
    richTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateStatus(textMessage)));
    return;
  }

  richTextBox.AppendText(textMessage + Environment.NewLine);
}
```